# Shell - sum of column on user

Tags: shell

Basically, I've two columns. First one stands for the users and the second one for the time they've spent on the server. So I'd like to sum for *each* client, how many minutes did he spend on the server.

```
user1 21:03
user2 19:55
user3 20:09
user1 18:57
user1 19:09
user3 21:05
user4 19:57
```

Let's say that I've this. I know how to split but there's one problem. Whenever I do `awk -F: '{print $1}` it prints users and the first parameter of the time (the number before `:`), and when I do `awk -F: '{print $2}` it prints only the numbers after `:`. After all of the sum, I'd like to get something like

```
user1 59:09
user2 19:55
user3 41:14
user4 19:57
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution:

```
perl -ne '/^(\S+) (\d\d):(\d\d)$/ or next; $t{$1} += $2 * 60 + $3; END { printf "%s %02d:%02d\n", $_, $t{$_} / 60, $t{$_} % 60 for sort keys %t }'
```

Or with better formatting:

```
perl -ne '
    /^(\S+) (\d\d):(\d\d)$/ or next;
    $t{$1} += $2 * 60 + $3;
    END {
        printf "%s %02d:%02d\n", $_, $t{$_} / 60, $t{$_} % 60
            for sort keys %t;
    }
'
```

We loop over all input lines (`-n`). We make sure every line matches the pattern `\S+ \d\d:\d\d` (i.e. a sequence of 1 or more non-space characters, a space, two digits, a colon, two digits) or else we skip it.

We accumulate the number of seconds per user in the hash `%t`. The keys are the user names, the values are the numbers.

At the end we print the contents of `%t` in a nicely formatted way.

Answer (score 0):

this is an awk solution

```
cat 1.txt | awk '{a[$1]+=substr($2,0,2)*60+substr($2,4)} END {for(i in a) printf("%s %02d:%02d\n", i,a[i]/60,a[i]%60)}'
user1 59:09
user2 19:55
user3 41:14
user4 19:57
```

first construct an array with index=$1, and the value = convert the time to an integer by minutes * 60 + seconds

```
{a[$1]+=substr($2,0,2)*60+substr($2,4)}
```

then print the array in the desired format which converts integer to a mi:ss format.

```
printf("%s %02d:%02d\n", i,a[i]/60,a[i]%60)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `awk` (and assuming the duration is always `hh:mm`, though their *sizes* can be arbitrary), the following will do the trick:

```
{
    split($2, flds, ":")               # Get hours and minutes.
    mins[$1] += flds[1] * 60 + flds[2] # Add to initially zero array item.
}
END {
    for (key in mins) {                # For each key in array.
        printf "%s %d:%02d\n",         # Output specific format.
            key,                       # Key, hours, and minutes.
            mins[key] / 60,
            mins[key] % 60
    }
}
```

That's the expanded, readable variant, the compressed one is shown in the following transcript, along with the output as expected:

```
pax> awk '{split($2,flds,":");mins[$1] += flds[1] * 60 + flds[2]}END{for(key in mins){printf "%s %d:%02d\n",key,mins[key]/60,mins[key]%60}}' testprog.in

user1 59:09
user2 19:55
user3 41:14
user4 19:57
```

---

Just keep in mind you haven't specified the input format whenever a user entry has more than 24 hours. If it goes something like `25:42`, the script will work as is.

If instead it decides to break out days (into something like `1:01:42` rather than `25:42`), you'll need to adjust how the minutes are calculated. This can be done relatively easily (*including* the possibility for minutes-only entries) by checking the `flds` array size with (in the main body of the script, the non-`END` bit):

```
num = split($2, flds, ":")
if (num == 1)      { add = flds[1] }
else if (num == 2) { add = flds[1] * 60 + flds[2] }
else               { add = flds[1] * 1440 + flds[2] * 60 + flds[3] }
mins[$1] += add
```